# Splitting vector into n amount of lists objects (R)

Tags: r, list, vector

I am looking to make a function that can split a vector of items into lists relative to the size of the list I provide the function

Say my function only took 2 items at a time, I would like to split this vector to look like this

```r
my_vector <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

# ideal function call
my_list <- obj_splitter(obj = my_vector, max_expressions = 2)

my_list
  : num [1:2] 1 2
  : num [1:2] 3 4
  : num 5
```

Current attempt:

```r
obj_splitter <- function(obj, max_expressions) {
  output_list <- list()
  size <- length(obj)

  if(length(obj) <= max_expressions) {
    return(obj)
  } else if(size > max_expressions){
    if(size%%max_expressions>0) {
      obj_counter <- ceiling(size/max_expressions)
      # i am unsure how to move the items from the vector into their respective list
      return(obj_counter)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
my_vector <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

obj_splitter <- function(obj, max) {
  split(obj, ceiling(seq_along(obj)/max))
}

my_list <- obj_splitter(my_vector, 2)

str(my_list)
#List of 3
# $ 1: num [1:2] 1 2
# $ 2: num [1:2] 3 4
# $ 3: num 5
```

You might still want to check some edge cases. If you want the output to not be named, you can wrap it in `unname`.

**Edit**: A bit more compact function.

Comment: this works perfectly! the names don't really matter because this is going to mapped into said initial function so I don't care what they're named